# Attribute appropriate amount of resource to run Mac OS + Windows + Ubuntu simultaneously

Tags: windows, memory, vmware, virtualization

I have a MacBook Pro where `VMWare Fusion` is installed to enable `Windows 7` and `Ubuntu`. One year ago, my system was well configured so that I could run `Mac OS`, `Windows` and `Ubuntu` at the same time. Later, I made some changes, probably around the attribution of cores and memories, now running the 3 systems simultaneously is very slow, although only running `Mac OS + Windows` or `Mac OS+Ubuntu` is fast enough. But I do need the 3 systems open for my work.

The resource for the 3 systems are listed as follows. Does anyone know how to arrange the ressource to re-enable the running of 3 systems simultaneously? Or does anyone have a good idea to make it possible?

Here is the resource of my Mac:
[image]

Here is the resource attributed to Ubuntu:
[image]

Here is the resource attributed to Windows:
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use `Parallels` for virtualization but I also run three OS simultaneously (`OSX`, `Windows 7` and `Windows 8`).

My settings are:
2 cores and 2 GB of RAM for each VM and more important `VT-x` support enabled, in your screenshot the first checkbox under Advanced Options.